# How to stream movies from LG Network Storage N2B1D to iPad, iPhone, Mac and TV?

Tags: macos, nas, streaming, iphone, ipad

I'm the owner of a brand new [*LG Network Storage N2B1D*](http://www.lgsolutions.com/products/digital-storage/network-attached-storage/n2b1d-2-bay-super-multi-nas-with-blu-ray-disc-rewriter).

I want to stream movies (or images) through a local network.
For now, I can browse files with a Mac or iPhone/iPad but I can't read content.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device actually has [a manual for that](http://www.lgsolutions.com/__downloads/pdf/n2b1-manual.pdf). There are two ways of streaming to devices: DLNA and iTunes sharing.

#### DLNA — Page 86:

> In order to activate or deactivate DLNA, the below procedures should be followed. Follow the below instructions.
>
> 1. Open DLNA from the webpage.
> 2. The top section will show the current status of DLNA. To activate the Media Server (DMS), click “apply”.
> 3. The source path refers to the location the multimedia data is currently saved. In order to utilize the multimedia data through DLNA, locations of the saved data must be determined. DLNA service will only be applicable to pre-set DLNA source folders.
> 4. To activate, please press the “apply” button. To deactivate, please select “Do not apply” and press the “apply” button.

So this means all you have to do is copy the data to `service\DLNA`.

---

#### iTunes Sharing — Page 97:

> Using the iTunes services and recreating music files stored to the LG Network Storage through PC/Mac iTunes programs is possible.
>
> For required use, select ‘Enable’ for iTunes Streaming Service.

Comment: Can I share movies with iTunes services ? And how to watch movies on an iPad ?

Comment: iTunes library sharing does not stream movies as far as I'm concerned. You will need [a DLNA capable player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients#iOS_:_iPhone.2C_iPod_touch.2C_iPad).

Comment: Too bad... so, I can't watch movies on my iPad. :-(

Comment: Well there are DLNA players for iPad I suppose? You might have to look online a bit, or ask on our [Apple.SE] sister site. This is as much as I can help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: OPlayer App is the solution I'm looking for. Cool...

Answer (score 2):

Install DLNA client on iPhone/iPad. I use ArkMC https://itunes.apple.com/UA/app/id405487397 with My Book Live WD NAS, works flawlessly.